# Mixing Auto-layout and non auto-layout views in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, autolayout

I have a view which uses auto-layout and is configured in Interface Builder. This view contains two sub views which each occupy half of the screen. To achieve this, I'm setting the height of one of the views to be half the height of the super view programatically.

```
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:bottomView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:contentInner attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:0.5 constant:0];
[contentInner addConstraint:constraint2];
```

The issues I'm having is that this view is called from another view controller which doesn't use auto-layout i.e.

```
- Main View 
-- View 1 (using auto-layout to position children)
---- topView
---- bottomView
```

I want to be able to set the size of view 1 manually and then for it to update it's children using the auto-layout rules. At the moment it calculates the sizes based on the outer frame size that is set in UIBuilder.

Is there a way to achieve this or am I going about it the wrong way?

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this. You just need to `[view1 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES]` after loading `view1` from the nib.